# Forced to deal with a & in an XML file, trying to resolve parse error $.ajax({...})

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Im forced to deal with an XML file that has multiple & in it, similar to :

```
<row>
    <value>Boys & Girls</value>
</row>
```

Heres my method :

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "data.xml",
    dataFilter : XMLFilter, //handles raw response data of XMLHttpRequest. pre-filtering to sanitize response. 
    async : false, //false means this has to complete before continuing
    success : XMLLoadedSuccess, //to be called if the request succeeds. 
    error : function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { debugger; },
    complete : XMLLoadedComplete //called when the request finishes after success / error callbacks are executed
});
```

The error is reported as :

```
textStatus : parse error
errorThrown : InvalidXML
```

Digging into the error, Im 99.99% sure its the & symbol peppered throughout.

I thought maybe the dataFilter parameter could be used to sanitize the response, but that seems to be called only after success. I was trying to do something like

```
function XMLFilter(data, type) {

    data = data.replace("&", "and");

    return data;
}
```

with it, but thats aparently not how to do this.

Then I thought, use php to load / filter out the & and write a new XML file, and have jQuery use that. This might work, but the XML file is like 500k in size. So maybe have a cron job that only does that once a day when the new XML is generated.

Bashing the person responsible for allowing the & in there is also an option but I dont see how it will help the end user.

Whats a good way to handle this?

Comment: Well you are getting an invalid XML file.  Saying that the file you received doesn't pass validation is acceptable, no need to bash someone, but having a vslid file might be useful to others besides you, or if they want to do domething else with it in the future.  Best to fix the root of the problem now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$.ajax()` doesn't specify `dataType`. Because `url` setting has .xml extension, JQuery infers the transferred data are XML (see: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax). This is wrong because of & incorrect encoding. You have to indicate that you want to transfer data as **text** with `dataType: 'text'` and then you process them.

In your case, data processing involves three steps:

1. replacing "&" with the corresponding XML entity: "&amp;"
2. convert the resulting string to XML.
3. processing  the resulting XML

This can be written:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  url: "data.xml",
  dataType: 'text',
  success: function(data) {
                var xml = jQuery.parseXML(data.replace("&", "&amp;"));
                process(xml);
            },
  ...
});
```